# Cannot Display Content In Kendo UI Editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a simple class below that I am trying to use to display the Content string in the Editor Kendo Control.  I am having issues binding the Property to the Editor.  How can I bind the Content String to the Kendo UI Web/MVC Editor using Razor?

```
public class Details
{
    public int TextId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public List<Details> TextDetails
{
    get
    {
        return mDetails;
    }
}




@model MyApp.MyModels.ContentModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditorContent";
}

<h2>Stuff To Display</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
.Name("editor")
.Value(Model.TextDetails.Content)
//I thought I could just bind to the property....  How can I show the Content in the Editor?
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do: `Model.TextDetails.First().Content`, Otherwise everything is fine. As you know `Value()` requires just a string value and renders as html content, providing appropriate model property (string) shouldn't hurt the editor.